# querysting binding error when using ServiceStack version 4.0.34 and OrmLiteCacheClient

Tags: servicestack

We're getting an "unable to bind to request" when calling a service with the following querystring:

```
/SomeService?playerid=59326&fromdate=4-1-2014&todate=12-11-2014
```

We have been using this querysting format for awhile now.

The problem is some either a change in 4.0.34, or something in the OrmLightCacheClient, which we had turned off for awhile and only just recently turned it back on.

If I change the dates to following format, it seems to work.

`/SomeService?playerid=59326&fromdate=2014-4-1&todate=2014-12-31`.

We can roll with the changed querystring date format for now, but wanted to report the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When supplying a date only (i.e. doesn't include a time) it [should be unambiguously defined](http://xkcd.com/1179/) using the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.